$f \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^4)$, $f_1(x)^2+f_2(x)^2=1=f_3(x)^2 + f_4(x)^2$. Prove that pullback of $f$ on every 3-form is $0$.
We have $f \in C^{\infty} (\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^4)$, $f = f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4$.
Elements of that transformation satisfy:
$$f_1(x)^2 + f_2(x)^2 = 1 = f_3(x)^2 + f_4(x)^2 \ \text{ for: } \ x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Prove that pullback using $f$ on every 3-form is equal to $0$.
$$f^*( \omega) = 0 \ \text{ for: } \ \omega \in \Omega^3(\mathbb{R}^4)$$

Solution:
We have $f: \mathbb{R^4} \to \mathbb{R}^4$.
I think that it can be said that both $f_1(x)^2 + f_2(x)^2 = 1$ and $f_1=3(x)^2 + f_4(x)^2 = 1$ are unit circles. Therefore we know that the product $f(\mathbb{R}^4)$ consists of $S_1 \times S_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$.
Because the image has dimension $2$ (because it consists of $2$ unit circles), the pullback as a 3-form on $\mathbb{R}^4$ is equal to $0$ because it can't be defined on image with dimension lesser than $3$.
My solution is based solely on intuition and is probably wrong. That's why I would like to ask for help.

Be careful how you describe this: The pullback is to $f$'s domain $\Bbb R^3$, which is 3-dimensional. It is because $f$ has to flatten $3$ dimensions down unto its 2D image that it cannot pull a $3$-form back to its domain without nullifying it.

There are few typos and\or inconsistencies in the domain of the codomain of your functions (e.g. on the first line of the solution, $f$'s domain is wrong, as is the domain of $f_i$ in your statement of the problem). Since the correct version is hard to determine from the text, I didn't edit myself.

I think your solution is essentially correct. Maybe the following is a bit more formal of an argument.
$f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^4$ is smooth, with it's image contained in $S^1\times S^1$. Since
$$S^1\times S^1\subset \mathbb{R}^4$$ is an embedded manifold, restricting the codomain of $f$ provides us with a smooth mapping $$\tilde{f}:\mathbb{R}^3\to S^1\times S^1.$$
See Corollary 5.20, J. Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds".
We also have:
$$
\begin{align}
f &= \iota \circ \tilde{f} \qquad\text{Where } \iota\text{ is the inclusion.}\\
\Rightarrow f^*&=\tilde{f}^* \circ \iota^* 
\end{align}
$$
We conclude by noting that $\iota^* : \Omega^3(\mathbb{R}^4)\to \Omega^3(S^1\times S^1)$, but the codomain of this pullback is the zero space.

Beautifully said. I think it's worth emphasizing that this has nothing to do with the dimension of the domain, only the dimension of the image of $f$.

Thank you @silvascientist. I’m not sure I understand your comment about the dimension of the domain. If I’m not mistaken, if we had $$f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^4,$$ We could have dropped all assumptions on the codomain, couldn’t we?

Oh, sure, you have to have dimension at least 3 in the domain to have any hope of seeing a nonzero pullback. But notice that there is a typo in the OP where the domain is stated as $\mathbb{R}^4$ and yet this does not affect the argument.
